# Select change not works

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have PartialView

Here is code

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Выберите проект</label>

    <select id="projectId" name="add_triangolazione" class="form-control">

    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">От:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefrom">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">До:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateto" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" data-date-split-input="true" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Наименование услуги:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Service", null, "XXXX", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "serviceIdProject" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">График работы:</label>
    <div>
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">С:</label>
        <input  type="time" class="form-control" id="workTime">

    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">По:</label>
        <input  type="time"" class="form-control" id="workTimeTo">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Количество:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="quantity"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Тариф:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="rate" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

It loading into modal via script

Here is script code

```
 $(document).on('click', '#addShow', function () {
    ShowAndPopulate();
});
function ShowAndPopulate() {

    $('#addProposalManager').load('/Manage/AddProposalManager', function () {
        let email = $('#userId').text();
        let getProposalsUrl = '/manage/populateprojects';
        model = {
            email: email
        },
        $.ajax({
                url: getProposalsUrl,
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var list = data;

                $.each(list, function (i, d) {
                    $('#projectId').append('<option value="' + d.Id + '">' + d.Name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        })
    });

}
```

Also in this field

> @Html.DropDownList("Service", null, "XXXX", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "serviceIdProject" })

I need to do something on value change

So I wrote this code at script

```
 $('#serviceIdProject').change(function () {
    alert("Gotcha!");
   // ServiceChange();
});
```

But when I change value, nothing happens.

Where can be my problem?

Thank's for help

Comment: Hi, is your code inside a document.ready block? This could be the problem.

Comment: Yes, It's inside it@LeonardoLeite

Comment: you are loading the html for the modal at click time.  #serviceIdProject doesn't exist yet.  you need to use .on() like you are doing at the top of your example to bind the change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using event delegation and also you seem to be using the wrong ID for the select:

```
$(document).on('change' , '#projectId' , function () {
    alert("Gotcha!");
   // ServiceChange();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, event delegation. Thank's!

Comment: @Silco your welcome , please accept the answer if it solves your problem.